# How to group jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We group jobs in jenkins using List View.
As result we have a lot of tabs.
But these guys can group jobs using other approach - https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com
On "All" page they have not only individual jobs, but also some groups.

```
For example:  
selenium-tests - job  
core - group
```

How is it possible to create these groups?
Is it a standard feature of Jenkins or some plugin is used?

Comment: I think that they are using the Jenkins Enterprise edition, not the standart open source one.  And it looks really awesome. How did they change the folder icons? I have only "default" and "git" icons in my dropdown menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the wondrous world of the Jenkins plugins; especially the [UI plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-UIplugins). I looks like Cloudbees uses the [Cloudbees Folder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin). I haven't used it since I am happy with the older [Nested view plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nested+View+Plugin).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the Folder plugin to group jobs. IMO it is more clear and easy to find things like this.
The full functionality is only on the Coudbees enterprise paid edition: [Setting environment variable in Cloudbees Jenkins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334163/setting-environment-variable-in-cloudbees-jenkins-folder)
You can still define folders, as groups or jobs, but not to use a common parameters to all of them.