# Grouping of jobs for assigning permissions possible in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I was hoping to be able to set up Jenkins to have some sort of grouping for jobs for controlling permissions. As far as I can tell, a job is equivalent to a project, is that correct? I'm using Active Directory authentication along with Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy. Is it possible (with any plug-ins) to have groups of jobs? Not asking about views or other GUI features ([How to group jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567072/how-to-group-jobs-in-jenkins)). Pointers to relevant documentation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) might do what you're looking for: with it you can define global or project roles, and control various permissions for each. Then you can assign roles to users (or groups of users).

To define project roles for a group of projects, the plugin can use pattern matching, so if you are consistently naming projects (jobs) you can easily define a group e.g. like: `[projectname]-.*` (matching each job that starts with the project name and a hyphen).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a further look. It seemed on the surface that that plugin would give me user based controls but not matrix those with groups of jobs.

Answer (score -1):

Using the answer above, and using the Role Base Plugin you can achieve that. The way to do it is to use parenthesis when defining the pattern. Say you have 2 jobs "Android Calculator" and a "iOS Checklist". And you want one role with access to both jobs. Since the names of the jobs are nothing alike using a pattern would be rather difficult. The plugin allows you to group them like listed bellow in pattern. Enjoy(Spent an afternoon looking for this answer):
   (Android Calculator|iOS Checklist)

Found my solution here: https://www.intropro.com/resources/blog/57-jenkins-configuration-how-to under the Jobs Naming Pattern section.